# Jquery ajax returning 404 not found

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using Ajax to pass my form data and files to a PHP file for processing.

**Javascript**:

```
$("form#applyform").submit(function(){

var data = new FormData();
jQuery.each($('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file);
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'ValidateApplication.php',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});

}
```

`ValidateApplication.php` definitely exists. I can view it if I type in the address into the web browser, however when I submit the form chrome console returns 404.

The PHP is in the same folder as the HTML page the JavaScript is running on so I am confused as to why I keep getting a 404.

UPDATE

Changing POST to GET gets rid of the 404 error, but returns a 500 Internal Server Error

UPDATE 2

Changing the action of the form to ="ValidateApplication.php" and submitting it as normal (without AJAX) leads to the correct file without any errors.

Comment: folder structure please

Comment: Is your capitalization correct? Certain operating systems/web servers treat capitalization differently. (i.e., `ValidateApplication.php` is not the same as `validateapplication.php` nor is `Validateapplication.php`)

Comment: try to use absolute path

Comment: Also, just for sake of testing, what happens if you use an absolute path instead of a relative path to the PHP file?

Comment: The capitalization is correct, the full URL is http://localhost/Scope%20Website/ValidateApplication.php
 and using the absolute path still gives the same error

Comment: Also, what's inside your `ValidateApplication.php`? Maybe you're returning some wrong headers if the request has the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seemed to be a problem with the `FormData` object. Once I changed my method to use `.serialize()` instead, the page worked just fine.

```
$("form#applyform").submit(function(){

    var data = $("form#applyform").serialize();
    jQuery.each($('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('file-'+i, file);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ValidateApplication.php',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have written it correct? Result of applying `serialize` is not something that has `append` method!

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue and after 2 hours looking for what was causing the 404 Not Found error I found that I was recently playing with the `header()` from PHP and had forgotten to delete the following line of code:

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
```

After deleting it, my Ajax functions became normal again.

Comment: I had spent 4 hours before finding your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was that I used an input field with `name="name"` which made the called page return a 404. Weird stuff, hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a / before the filename:
url: '/ValidateApplication.php',

Try changing the request type from POST to GET and see if it works.

Try commenting out parts of the code:

```
/*cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false,*/
```

Try another browser.

Comment: The / before the filename results in it using the root directory which doesn't work. (Goes to http://localhost/ValidateApplication.php instead of http://localhost/Scope%20Website/ValidateApplication.php which is where the file is).

Comment: Changing it to GET works but results in Error 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Commenting those lines out causes Illegal Invocation error

Comment: It is difficult to see exactly what is wrong without seeing the actual data going to and from your pc and the server. Can you sniff the packet and post it? What is the contents of the php file? Is it handling the incoming data correctly?

What about the datatype? Is it JSON? Comment out all the lines in the php file and var_dump($_POST) to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Please validate you have provided name="" attribute properly in the form
Form submit validate all bean attribute from name attribute of the input

Answer (score 0):

Please check your PHP page name!

Do not use `page-ajax.php`, but instead use `page_ajax.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my case, I'd be sure to recheck your url address.

Comment: The answer is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Most probably you have renamed the file ValidateApplication.php
or forgotten to rename.