# Ajax post not found 404 error returned

Tags: php, ajax, xml, curl

I am trying to make a call with Ajax to a .php file. But with all the Ajax calls I make to a file I get the same response:

`POST http://url.com/file.php 404 (Not Found)`

I've tried an absolute path and a relative path, but both doesn't work. I also have added the header for Access-Control-Allow-Origin. So that can not be the problem.

But if I pase the path directly in my browser I get the result that I need to see.

But I really can't figure out why I am receiving this error.

This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : defaultUrl + "xml/argument1/argument2/" + filiaalId + "/",
    dataType : 'html',
    success : function(data){
    }
});
```

Comment: Try with `type: 'GET'` instead (or any other way you do in ajax).

Comment: @SabujHassan That does not work, and I need to use POST here

Comment: When you paste the url into browser it actually does GET request, not POST. That's why I've suggested you that.

Comment: @SabujHassan Ahh oke thank you very much, I did not knew that. Sadly it doesn't work :(

Comment: one little note make sure u place ur url and data data: {} in ajax distinct and debug the correct url generated by using it. i mean defaultUrl + "xml/argument1/argument2/" + filiaalId + "/" what is this url looks like when u run it ?

Comment: check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370186/jquery-ajax-returning-404-not-found

Comment: @RaviHirani I am sorry for the late reaction, but this still does not work. I really can not find the problem. Any other suggestions?